# Number of processes in text (batch) mode

Tags: kernel, licensing

I have tex mode access to server with Mathematica
the math sesion parameters are:

```
In[1]:= $ProcessorCount                                                                                              
Out[1]= 12
In[2]:= $MaxLicenseProcesses                                                                                         
Out[2]= 2
In[3]:= $MaxLicenseSubprocesses                                                                                      
Out[3]= 8
```

When I try tu run more then 2 batch processes i got the license limit error.

```
math < file1.m &   OK
sleep 5
math < file2.m &   OK
sleep 5
math < file3.m &   Error
```

Is there a way to use Subprocess instead Process (in batch mode) ?

The next question is : Why i have to use sleep ? If I did not use it, I got the license error in the second process

with regards, Olaf

Comment: Oh. Ah. I see. Sorry for my wrongful edit...